# Extract values from pandas groupby() into a new dataset combining single values and numpy arrays

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, group-by

I have a pandas dataframe called `df` that looks like this

```
name   test_type   test_number   correct
joe    0           1             1
joe    0           2             0
joe    1           1             0
joe    1           2             1
joe    0           1             1
joe    0           2             1
jim    1           1             0
jim    1           2             1
jim    0           1             0
jim    0           2             1
jim    1           1             0
jim    1           2             0
```

I want a dataset that groups by `name`, and extract the mean value of `correct` by `test_type` (as a single value) as well as the mean value of correct by `test_type` and `test_number` (as a `numpy` array).

Here is what I need:

```
name    correct_0    correct_1    correct_0_by_tn    correct_val_1_by_tn
joe     0.75         0.5          [1, 0.5]           [0, 1]
jim     0.5          0.25         [0, 1]             [0, 0.5]
```

I've been using `df.groupby(["name", "test_type"]).correct.mean().reset_index()` and `df.groupby(["name", "test_type", "test_number"]).correct.mean().reset_index()` but I can't manage to 1) extract the mean by `test_number` as an array like I want to and 2) organize the output in a coherent dataframe.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit on your conditions ? if I understand correctly, the value [0.5, 1] in `correct_0_by_tn` is the average of column correct (when correct is 0), based on test_number. 

But, for name `jim` , why does `correct_0_by_tn` is only `[0.5]`. `Jim` has two different test_numbers. Hence, it should result in two different averages right ?

Comment: @srinath you're right, I'm sorry, the values I put were incorrect. I edited it now. `correct_0_by_tn` is the average of column `correct` when `test_type` is 0, divided by `test_number` such that the first cell in the output array is the mean of `correct` when `test_type` is 0 and `test_number` is 1. Does that make sense?

Comment: why would joe/correct_1 be 1? the third row (joe/1/1/0) has correct = 0

Comment: @mozway thanks for catching that, it's correct now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use:

```
A = df.groupby(['name', 'test_type'], sort=False)['correct'].mean().unstack()

B = (df
   .groupby(['name', 'test_type', 'test_number'])['correct'].mean()
   .unstack().agg(list, axis=1).unstack()
)

out = A.join(B.add_suffix('_by_tn')).add_prefix('correct_')
```

output:

```
test_type  correct_0  correct_1 correct_0_by_tn correct_1_by_tn
name                                                           
joe             0.75       0.50      [1.0, 0.5]      [0.0, 1.0]
jim             0.50       0.25      [0.0, 1.0]      [0.0, 0.5]
```

Alternative output:

```
out = (A
  .join(B.add_suffix('_by_tn'))
  .add_prefix('correct_')
  .rename_axis(columns=None)
  .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
  name  correct_0  correct_1 correct_0_by_tn correct_1_by_tn
0  joe       0.75       0.50      [1.0, 0.5]      [0.0, 1.0]
1  jim       0.50       0.25      [0.0, 1.0]      [0.0, 0.5]
```